# Firebase Functions: the rewrites do nothing

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I tried to set up a blog with Angular Universal (package for Server-Side-Rendering) following this tutorial: https://hackernoon.com/deploy-angular-universal-w-firebase-ad70ea2413a1

The /dist folder seems to get served and if I don't delete index.html from it, it serves the non-prerendered app correctly. But in order to get the prerendered app, I am supposed to delete index.html. As I can see in console output this works too - I get calls like

```
[hosting] Rewriting / to live function ssr
[hosting] Rewriting /favicon.ico to live function ssr
```

But they all time out. I thought my index.js is faulty, so I replaced it with a dummy (from google's firebase tutorial):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.ssr = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const hours = (new Date().getHours() % 12) + 1; // london is UTC + 1hr;
    res.status(200).send(`<!doctype html>
    <head>
      <title>Time</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      ${'BONG '.repeat(hours)}
    </body>
  </html>`);
});
```

still, no response and I get timeouts in the browser. when I do a `curl -v` I get:

```
curl http://localhost:5000 -v
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:5000/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to ::1 port 5000 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Timeout
< Date: Sun, 11 Mar 2018 15:12:11 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 42
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
Timed out waiting for function to respond
```

How do I go on about debugging this? I am testing everything locally with `firebase serve`, but I get the  same problems on remote deploys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `firebase serve --only functions,hosting`? AFAIK `firebase serve` runs just the hosting module which is not setting up the functions (even if they're specified in the config).